# Playing a game of SCORE!

Tags: probability

There are 4 people playing a game of SCORE!. In the game of SCORE!, every player rolls 2 dice, and adds their sum. The players win if the sum of all 8 dice is more than 17. What is the probability the players win?

---

I was thinking of using casework, but I felt that it was perhaps too bashy. Is there a better method?

Comment: Sounds like an exciting game!

Answer (score 0):

For an exact answer, I would make a spreadsheet.  Start with some blank lines, then put the numbers $1$ through $48$ in column A.  The table will have the number of ways to make each sum from a number of dice.  The number of dice will increase from $1$ in column B to $8$ in column I.  Put $1$ in the rows from $1$ to $6$ in column B as there is $1$ way to get each sum from one die.  To the right, each cell is the sum of the cells one column to the left and one to six rows up, corresponding to the fact that you can start with each of those sums and have the last die make the number on the row.  Copy down and copy right make ths easy.  Finally add all the numbers in the rows $18$ through $48$ and divide by $6^8$